# Titanium Alloy ListView Custom Template Click Not Working

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm using a custom template with views inside on a ListView, but what happens is that the click do not work. I tried to disable touchEnabled on all views inside and still nothing.

In the example below and in the attachment that I am including, there are two ListViews, one with a template with Views inside, and another ListView with a template with no Views inside.

Tested on emulator iOS 10.0.0

```
[index.xml]
<Alloy>
<Window class="container" layout="vertical">
    <Label text="Click is not working on a template with views inside (tested iOS 10.0.0)" top="30"/>
    <ListView id="list1" defaultItemTemplate="temp1" height="200" allowsSelection="false" separatorColor="transparent" top="10" onItemClick="testClick">
        <Templates>
            <ItemTemplate name="temp1" onClick="testClick">
                <View backgroundColor="blue">
                    <View backgroundColor="red" width="60%" height="90%">
                        <Label bindId="label1"/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </Templates>
        <ListSection headerTitle="Click DON'T WORK!" fontSize="12">
            <ListItem label1:text="01" />
            <ListItem label1:text="02" />
            <ListItem label1:text="03" />
        </ListSection>
    </ListView>
    <ListView id="list2" defaultItemTemplate="temp2" height="200" allowsSelection="false" separatorColor="transparent">
        <Templates>
            <ItemTemplate name="temp2" onClick="testClick" >
                <View backgroundColor="cyan">
                </View>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </Templates>
        <ListSection headerTitle="Click WORKS!">
            <ListItem />
            <ListItem />
            <ListItem />
        </ListSection>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

```
[index.js]
function testClick() {
 alert('CLICK');
}

$.index.open();
```

Download the project if you need:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3h6mchsb0e5bdh/ListViewBugTemplateClick.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **onItemclick** the C is lowercase, and it should work but remove this onClick`<ItemTemplate name="temp1" onClick="testClick">`

```
<ListView id="list1" defaultItemTemplate="temp1" height="200" separatorColor="transparent" top="10" onItemclick="testClick">
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="temp1">
                    <View backgroundColor="blue">
                        <View backgroundColor="red" width="60%" height="90%">
                            <Label bindId="label1"/>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <ListSection headerTitle="Click DON'T WORK!" fontSize="12">
                <ListItem label1:text="01" label1:touchEnabled="false" label1:touchable="false" />
                <ListItem label1:text="02"/>
                <ListItem label1:text="03" />
            </ListSection>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I made sure that C is in lowercase and removed the onClick from the template. After many hours wasting time in making this work, I recreated the list in Javascript, and it is working. I'm really believing it's a bug, If you could test the project maybe would happen with you too. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: i downloaded your code and put the code you see in there an it popped up the clicked me alert.. same simulator.. did you try copying and pasting that code? also remove allowsSelection=false

Comment: You're right, I copied and pasted and it worked. Was allowSelection too! That was so dumb of my part! Thank you!

Comment: Done, but I got a message that I have less than 15 reputation, will not show publicly.